# Services are not running parallel

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

I made 2 different services (differently listed in Manifest) which have 2 different AsyncTask inside them. I run them from 2 different fragments (same activity).

But if I run them simultaneously, one service get queued till other service finishes. When I had those AsyncTask inside fragment directly (without using service), I could run them in parallel.

Is there anyway I can run them in parallel using service?

Thanks,

**Code of Each Service Class is similar to:**

```
public class MyServiceClass extends Service{

    public boolean isCancelled = false;
    DownloadFile downloadFile;
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("com.example.STOP");
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        downloadFile = new DownloadFile();
        downloadFile.execute();
        return 0;
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(action.equals("com.example.STOP")){
                isCancelled = true;
            }

        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        if (downloadFile != null && downloadFile.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
            downloadFile.cancel(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> 
    {
        NotificationManager mNotifyManager;
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
        int mId = 2;
        Context context;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            context = getApplicationContext();
            if(context!=null){
                Intent newintent = new Intent();
                newintent.setAction("com.example.STOP");
                PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, newintent, 0);
                mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
                mBuilder.setContentTitle("Cover Download")
                    .setContentText("In progress")
                    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... args) {
               DOING TASKS
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, values[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result1) 
        {
            mBuilder.setContentText(result1).setProgress(0,0,false);
            mNotifyManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
            context = null;
            MyServiceClass.this.stopSelf();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDITED CODE USING INTENTSERVICE**

```
public class MyImportServiceClass extends IntentService{

    public MyImportServiceClass() {
        super("MyImportServiceClass");
    }

    RemoteConnectivity importExport;
    String code;

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("CHECKPOINT","INTENT START");
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("com.example.MyImportServiceClass.STOPIMEX");
        String data = intent.getStringExtra("data");
        code = intent.getStringExtra("code");
        registerReceiver(imreceiver, filter); // TO CANCEL ASYNCTASK WHEN USER CLICK ON NOTIFICATION


importExport = new RemoteConnectivity();
        importExport.execute(code,data);
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver imreceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(action.equals("com.example.MyImportServiceClass.STOPIMEX")){
                if (importExport != null && importExport.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
                    importExport.cancel(true);
                }
            }

        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d("CHECKPOINT","DESTROY");
        unregisterReceiver(imreceiver);
        if(code.equals("1") || code.equals("2") || code.equals("6")){
            Log.d("CHECKPOINT","DESTROY ANNOUNCE TO MAIN THREAD");
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction("com.example.MyImportServiceClass.UPDATE");
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
        }

    }

    private class RemoteConnectivity extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
    {
        NotificationManager mNotifyManager;
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
        int mId;
        Context context;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.d("CHECKPOINT","PREEXECUTE");
            context = getApplicationContext();
            Intent newintent = new Intent();
            newintent.setAction("com.example.MyImportServiceClass.STOPIMEX");
            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, newintent, 0);

            mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
            mBuilder.setContentTitle("Import/Export")
                    .setContentText("In progress")
                    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            Log.d("CHECKPOINT","START BACKGROUND");
            .............
            .............
            Log.d("FLAGPOINT","IMPORTING");
            mylibmandbhandler db = new mylibmandbhandler(context);
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        //DOING THINGS
                if(isCancelled){
                    db.close();
                    return null;
                }
            }
            db.close();
            return "done";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result1) 
        {
            Log.d("CHECKPOINT","COMPLETED");

        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled(){
            Log.d("CHECKPOINT","CANCELLED");

        }
    }
}
```

**LOGCAT**

```
01-03 06:49:36.367: D/CHECKPOINT(2019): INTENT START
01-03 06:49:36.387: D/CHECKPOINT(2019): PREEXECUTE
01-03 06:49:36.397: D/CHECKPOINT(2019): START BACKGROUND
01-03 06:49:36.457: D/CHECKPOINT(2019): DESTROY
01-03 06:49:36.457: D/CHECKPOINT(2019): ANNOUNCE
01-03 06:49:36.997: D/FLAGPOINT(2019): IMPORTING
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services run in the UI thread, so the OS will decide which service goes first and when it will be stopped. If I were you I would change your Service classes for IntentService as they have their own working thread. I think that will be useful in order to get them running at the same time.

Comment: thanks for your comment ...I changed Service to IntentService class .. but can't understand where should I put the codes of current onDestroy method. If you plz help ...

Comment: First as your IntentService will stop by itself you can remove your call to `MyServiceClass.this.stopSelf()`. Second I would recommend you to implement `onHandleIntent` if you need to check new Intent parameters. Finally I don't see why you have to change your `onDestroy` code, is it not getting called?

Comment: (sorry having terrible internet today, hence delayed) .. anyway, yes indeed .. onDestroy is getting called before PostExecute (of AsyncTask) ! I updated my post to give my last code and logcat, if you kindly check .. and it is not consistent as well (sometimes called just after PREEXECUTE !!)

Comment: The problem I see here is that you are launching an AsyncTask inside the Intentservice, when you create an asyncTask you are creating ANOTHER thread in your application, my advice would be to remove the Asynctask as the IntentService can handle a new Intent to close the process and the `DoInBackground` code can be executed inside the `IntentService` as it has its own working thread.